# Modal validation in MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

how can i validate modal with partialview page?
here is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modalid" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBodyid">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

button

```
<input type="submit" onclick="functionname()" value="Add Data" />
```

javascript

```
function functionname() {
    $("#Modalid").modal();
    $("#ModalLabelid").html("YourTitle");
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#Modalid');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    $("#ModalBodyid").load("RegistrationForm/Create");
    return false;
}
```

Controller to load in my modal body

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_test");
    }
```

In my partial view _test has a button that will execute the DataManipulate Controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DataManipulate", "RegistrationForm", 
FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "FormID" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
}
```

And here is the controller for the button in my partialview

```
public ActionResult DataManipulate([Bind(Include = "Firstname,Lastname,Gender,Birthday,Address,City, Country,Civil,HomeTelephone,OfficeTelephone,MobileTelephone, Login, Password, Email, TransPIN")] Properties userInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                if (myModel.addNewData(userInfo, conn))
                {
                    TempData["msg"] = "Data Successfully added";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (myModel.UpdateData(userInfo, counter, conn))
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    TempData["msg"] = "Data Successfully Updated";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My problem is when the modal state is not valid the page reload to another page. what i want is to stay the modal open with the validation error.

Is there any way to do that?I am beginner in MVC Please help me..
Thanks...